# Why my json_encode is not giving proper value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to receive data from database based on the name entered by user, everything works fine I do see the value on screen   and no error Here is the php code :

```
 <?php
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";
 mysql_connect($dbhost,$username,$password);
 @mysql_select_db("trynew") or die(mysql_error());
 $user ="mon";  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM trynewtable where name = '$user' ";
 $all_result = array();
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 if($result==FALSE)
 {
  die(mysql_error());
 }
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $all_result[] = $row;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$jsondata = json_encode($all_result);echo $jsondata;
mysql_close();
?>
```

but the output that I see on the html div is :

```
[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"mon","Name":"mon","2":"26","Age":"26","3":"F","Gender":"F"}]
```

Actual data stored in the database is :
The actual data in the database

[image]

Kindly let me know what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why are you suppressing errors? Why are you still using `mysql_`? You should be switching from MySQL as it has been [officially](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) deprecated. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) **with** [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `mysql_fetch_array()` which will return both the numerically keyed and associative array of data in your database. Either use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or `mysql_fetch_array()` with `MYSQL_ASSOC` as the second parameter to get only the associative array.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

or

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

FYI, the mysql_ API is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and was [removed in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot... my problem got resolved... I will switch to mysqli, I am new to php so didn't know about mysqli

Comment: Could you please let me know another thing json_encode converts the array to object but in the javaScript code :
 When I try to get the whole object on the screen like :
'jsonData = xhr.responseText;
   document.getElementById("dvID").innerHTML = jsonData;' It is fine  but when I want to access any particular value like age 
'jsonData = xhr.responseText;
   document.getElementById("dvID").innerHTML = jsonData.age;' , it gives undefined , Could you please tell me why ?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing a full example. If you can't figure it out ask a new question and post a properly formatted example and we can all try to help you sort it out.

Comment: Please see my question on accessing object property    [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953581/why-am-i-not-able-to-fetch-property-of-the-object-that-i-get-from-php#) Could you please answer ?